# .htaccess masking directory with or without slash

Tags: .htaccess, directory, masking

I'm trying to mask a directory with some static html content, the simple example would be like this:
`RewriteRule ^something/?$ sub_directory/something/`

Now, when the user follows a ulr like

`www.example.com/something/`

everything works fine, the static page loads from `sub_directory/something` with css and images. But when the user follows an url like this: `www.example.com/something` (without trailing slash), the application returns 404 error.

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried:

`RewriteRule ^something(.*) sub_directory/something/$1`

But this way, only html content is loaded without any js, css or image files.

Comment: Tha paths would be `sub_directory/something/css` ,  `sub_directory/something/images`  and  `sub_directory/something/js` etc. Js and Css also have minified files. In html, the path is `images/image.jpg` etc.

Comment: How are these css being included in your HTML? Can you share an example?

Comment: This would be an css example from the html: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css?v1">` and js `<script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:js|css|images)/.+$ sub_directory/something/$0 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^something(?:/.*)?$ sub_directory/$0 [L,NC]
```

And add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/sub_directory/something/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: This way I get an 404 error like this `The requested URL /sub_directory/something/something/` for both cases, with and without trailing slash.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) this solves my problem, but I gotta know (been banging my head over this for a while now), is there any way to make this work without changing the html file?

Comment: I would get `www.domain.com/images/image.jpg`, same for css and js files.

Comment: It works, but this is a problem for me. It happens that I can't rewrite any css, img or js file. This is a multisite application, and there are images, js and css directories in the root directory that are needed for other things. However I did change `base` tag's `href` value to `"/something/"` instead of `"/sub_directory/something/"`with this rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^something(.*) sub_directory/something/$1` and it works in both cases, with or without trailing slash. When I add `?:/` to the mix, it just redirects me to `example.com/sub_directory/something/`. I'll be damned if I know why.

Comment: In any case `<base ...>` is my preferred solution that I recommend to everyone in this situation. Also note `RewriteRule ^something(?:/.*)?$ sub_directory/$0 [L,NC]` is pretty much same but just safer since `^something(.*)` will also match `something123` or `something-something`